# How can I use a variable to take an object out of a json?

Tags: javascript

I have a small question that I can't get my head around.

```
let content = getData() //This will return a json in the variable content
content[0] //This is the output that i want but instead of [0], I want to store this into a variable

let path = "[0]"
content.path //something like that but the good way, can't figure it out how i could do this
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to store in the variable index or property name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store a property name then you can do the following:

```js
const propertyToAccess = "someProperty";
const value = content[propertyToAccess];

console.log(value) // Will be the JSON value at that property.
```

Or if you want to access an array of objects by an index:

```js
const indexToAccess = 5; // Or any index inside the array
const value = content[indexToAccess];

console.log(value) // Will be the JSON value at that property.
```

Answer (score 4):

Try with bracket notation as this allows dynamic value as key name:

```
let path = "0";
content[path]
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
let path = 0
let value = content[path]
```

these things are equivalent:

```
let prop = "property_name"
let value = obj[prop]
```

```
let value = obj["property_name"]
```

```
let value = obj.property_name
```